# Передать значение переменной из js в php и сохранить его в базу данных

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

Имеется форма (см. фото). В первом столбце находятся select с номерами датчиков. Для каждого датчика существует постоянный набор параметров. Если выбран датчик с номером 61417 то, в другие колонки всегда вставляются одни и те же значения (т.е 0,2,10,4,36 и т.д). Если выбран любой другой сенсор, то вставляются другие значения, соответствующие этому сенсору. Одновременно может быть задействовано до 10 датчиков. Также, на этой странице расположены inputs, в которые пользователь может вводить данные. Эти данные должны сохраняться в базе данных и при необходимости должны выводится на страницу из б.д. Я правильно понимаю, что так как в форме с сенсорами может быть использовано несколько сенсоров, то данные должны сохраняться в отдельную таблицу  базы данных будучи в массиве и затем соединяться с таблицей в которой сохраняются данные с input-ов через foreign key?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно передать значение переменной из js в php и сохранить его в базу данных. Однако в базу данных сохраняется две строки(см.фото), в одной значения которые вводятся в форму в поле input, а в другую строку значение которое передается из js. Почему это происходит и как решить эту проблему?

[image]

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
 
<script>
 
let type = 0;
let element = 0;
 
 
function seltag2(){
let p = document.all["sensor1"].value;
     switch(p){
        case "1":
            type = 77;
            element = 8;
            break;  
 
        case "2":
             type = 70;
             element = 1;
            break;
    
    }
    document.getElementById('t20_1').innerHTML=element;
    
 
 
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'insert_data_to_db.php',                
    data: {element:element},
 success: function(data) {
 
 }
 
})
 
}
 
</script>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
 
include_once 'connection.php';
 
$element=$_POST['element'];
 
$report_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['report_no']);
$element = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['element']);
 
// Attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO protocoldata (report_no, element) VALUES ('$report_no', '$element')";
if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    echo "New record created successfully.";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
?>
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="ultrasonic" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data' 
action="insert_data_to_db.php">
<div id="t1y_1" class="t s3">
    <div class="sensor1">
        <select name="sensor1" id="sensor1" form="ultrasonic" onchange ="seltag2()">
             <option value="0" dissabled>none</option>
             <option value="1">61417</option>
             <option value="2">4056</option>
        </select>
    
     </div>
</div>

<div id="t4k_1" class="t s2"><div class="report_no"><input type="text" name="report_no" form="ultrasonic"/></div></div>

<input type="submit" value="Add data" name="upload" form="ultrasonic" id="add_data"> </div>

</form>
```

**SQL**

```
   -- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.5
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Хост: 127.0.0.1
-- Время создания: Июн 03 2021 г., 09:50
-- Версия сервера: 10.1.38-MariaDB
-- Версия PHP: 7.3.2

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- База данных: `protocol`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Структура таблицы `protocoldata`
--

CREATE TABLE `protocoldata` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `work_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `report_no` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `protocol_name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `purchaser` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `probe` varchar(1) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `element` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name0` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Индексы сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- Индексы таблицы `protocoldata`
--
ALTER TABLE `protocoldata`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для сохранённых таблиц
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT для таблицы `protocoldata`
--
ALTER TABLE `protocoldata`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=733;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

**Connection.php**

```
<?php

$host = "localhost"; /* Host name */
$user = "protocol"; /* User */
$password = "11111"; /* Password */
$dbname = "protocol"; /* Database name */

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
  die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Comment: Где у вас `input`? Почему не передается `report_no`?

Comment: Забыл добавить здесь input. Исправил и добавил фото, на котором видно создаваемые 2 строки в бд

Comment: У вас наверное еще там и форма есть?

Comment: Имеется, добавил

Comment: форма когда сабмитится?

Comment: При нажатии кнопки, также добавил

Comment: У вас записывается в бд при выборе `select` - `onchange ="seltag2()"` с помощью ajax запроса. Еще записывается в бд, когда форма сабмитится. Что вы хотите сделать то?

Comment: Нужно чтобы при выборе того или иного значения из select, вставлялись бы правильные данные в ячейки таблицы. А после этого эти данные вместе с другими данными (которые ввел пользователь) можно было бы сохранить в базу данных, в одну запись

Comment: Тогда уберите вызов ajax из `seltag2` и измените `name="element"` для `select`. Будут данные сохранятся при сабмите формы.

Comment: При таких изменениях в базу данных в столбец "element" записывается значение option value из select (1 или 2).

Comment: И это логично! Заполните  option value нужными вам значениями!

Comment: С option value не получится, описал более подробно что требуется сделать

Comment: Да вам в разведчики надо идти работать!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почему бы Вам не повесить обработчик события на вашу кнопку отправки формы
И не сделать e.preventDefault();
ещё не забудьте добавить атрибут вот тут value:

```html
<input type="text" id="report_no" name="report_no" form="ultrasonic"/>
```

код страницы где форма:

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js" integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <form id="ultrasonic" method="POST" enctype='multipart/form-data'
          action="insert_data_to_db.php">
        <div id="t1y_1" class="t s3">
            <div class="sensor1">
                <select name="sensor1" id="sensor1" form="ultrasonic" onchange="seltag2()">
                    <option value="0" dissabled>none</option>
                    <option value="1">61417</option>
                    <option value="2">4056</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="t4k_1" class="t s2">
            <div class="report_no"><input type="text" id="report_no" name="report_no" form="ultrasonic"/></div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="Add data" name="upload" form="ultrasonic" id="add_data"> </div>
    </form>

<script>
    let type = 0;
    let element = 0;
    const send_btn = document.getElementById('add_data');
    const report_no = document.getElementById('report_no');
    let div = document.createElement('div');
    div.className = "alert";

    function seltag2() {
        let p = document.all["sensor1"].value;
        switch (p) {
            case "1":
                type = 77;
                element = 8;
                break;

            case "2":
                type = 70;
                element = 1;
                break;

        }
        // document.getElementById('t20_1').innerHTML=element;

    }

    send_btn.onclick = function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'insert_data_to_db.php',
            data: {
                element:element,
                report_no:report_no.value
            },
            success: function (data) {
                document.getElementById('ultrasonic').reset();
                console.log(data);
                div.innerHTML = '<strong>'+data+'</strong>';
                document.body.append(div);
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

код insert_data_to_db.php:

```
<?php
    if (!isAjax()) die;
    include_once 'connection.php';
    $element = $_POST['element'];

    $report_no = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['report_no']);
    $element = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['element']);

    // Attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO protocoldata (report_no, element) VALUES ('$report_no', 
                                                                        '$element')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New record created successfully.";
    } else {
      echo "Error: ".$sql."<br>".mysqli_error($conn);
    }

    function isAjax(){
       return (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && 
               (strtolower(getenv('HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH')) === 'xmlhttprequest'));
   }
```

Comment: Попробовал предложенный вами код, однако кнопка отправки формы становится вообще неактивной, т.е не нажимается. А если убрать e.preventDefault(); то нажимается, но запись в базе данных не появляется

Comment: Вы добавили JQuery перед javascript кодом(<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>)? Вы добавили кнопки Атрибут id (id="add_data")? что выводит консоль браузера когда жмете кнопку? Я подправил чуть чуть код попробуйте ещё раз...

Comment: Теперь кнопка нажимается, но данные не сохраняются в б.д. Добавил более развернутое описание что требуется сделать.

Comment: У вас нет никаких ошибок нигде ничего не пишется когда вы жмете на кнопку?
например Error: INSERT INTO protocoldata (report_no, element) ?

Comment: Никаких ошибок, проверил еще раз код, все совпадает, скорее всего с ajax какая-то беда и  выполняется это условие if (!isAjax()) die;

Comment: Скиньте sql вот этой таблицы `protocoldata` и содержимое файла 'connection.php';
потому что я скопировал код он работает)) у меня таблица protocoldata содержит две колонки report_no, element записывает и input и для 61417 : 8 а для 4056 : 1 скидывать скрины не нужно скиньте код таблицы sql чтоб я смог создать такую же себе таблицу зайдите в phpmyadmin Выберите таблицу protocoldata и сделайте экспорт и код в студию а ещё лучше дайте Telegram свой

Comment: Добавил код выше

Comment: https://t.me/Judgin82